Filtering WP query by a Term from an ACF relationship post
My situation:
I have two custom post types: office and employee. With help of an ACF Relationship field you can select an employee when editing the office post type.
The employee post type has a term called availability (terms: yes,no).
I want to filter my office query to only show the right employees when they have the term "yes" selected.
What I have so far is the code below that filters the employee who is assigned to the office. How can I add the last part that filters out by terms of the employee post type?
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'office',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'ASC'
);

$args['meta_query'][] = array(
  'key'     => 'acf_employee_relationship_field',
  'value'   => $selected_office,
  'compare' => 'LIKE', 
);


Does this help? Look at the way meta_query is formed.

@FiddlingAway unfortunately not.

I think you need to have two queries. You can change your query to only get the IDs of the employees you need. In another query you can filter the employees by taxonomy term ID.

I found a somewhat ugly solution. I've created a new acf field for the office post type that automatically get's filled with the value of the "availability" term based on the selected relationship field. And now I can just add an extra metaquery argument.
